# Unsupported locale setting for AWS EB client

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am following this [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html#create_deploy_Ruby_rails_ebinit), but am unable to install AWS EB client

`sudo pip install awsebcli`

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in 
>       sys.exit(main())
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/**init**.py", line
>   215, in main
>
> ```
> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
> ```
>
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/locale.py", line 579, in setlocale
>
> ```
> return _setlocale(category, locale)
> ```
>
> locale.Error: unsupported locale setting

How do I fix this

> unsupported locale setting

issue?

I have searched around quite a bit but can't find anything specific to my issue.

Note that I alr have Python 2.7.10 on my aws ec2 instance. Also, my region is asia pacific.

Answer (score 5):

you'll need:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```